# DevExpress Collection Filter and BetweenOperator

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm trying to use the BetweenOperator with to get properties in my object.  Both properties are of type string and I need to convert to ints.

string homeML;

```
int ii = 100;
                int jj = 105;

                //Attempt 1
                CriteriaOperator filter = new BetweenOperator("homeML", ii, jj);
                RangeCollection.Filter = filter;
            
                //Attempt2
                RangeCollection.Filter = CriteriaOperator.Parse("Convert.ToInt16([homeML]) > ? AND Convert.ToInt16([homeML] < ?", ii, jj);
```

Both attempts give me the wrong answer.

"DevExpress.Data.Filtering.Exceptions.CriteriaParserException: 'Parser error at line 0, character 15: syntax error; ("Convert.ToInt16{FAILED HERE}([homeML]) > ? AND Convert.ToInt16([homeML] < ?")'"

I've tried two different attempts, both have failed.

How do I do the conversion of the string properties and get results in my collection that has a range of records?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use functions listed in the following article in criteria operator: [Criteria Language Syntax](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/4928/devexpress-data-library/criteria-language-syntax#operators). C# methods don't work. To cast a string to an integer value, use `ToInt(Value)`.